# I want to concatenate a single quote at the end of the string

Tags: php

I want to concat a single quote at the end of the string
How can i do this thing in php?

```
    $file = $this->form->getValue('doc');
    $filename = $file->getOriginalName();
    $file_name=$fn.'_'.md5($fiename);
    $extension = $file->getExtension($file->getOriginalExtension());
```

Comment: yes concat. i want to concat

Comment: i have a string and i want to concat single quote at the end of that string

Comment: $filename, $fiename, $file_name, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$file_name=$fn.'_'.md5($fiename).",";
```

in php `.` is used for concat.

Comment: Single quote, not a comma :)

Comment: it's not important, OP can bind anything what he want.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$file = $this->form->getValue('doc');
$filename = $file->getOriginalName();
$file_name=$fn.'_'.md5($filename); //There is no $fiename, so i changed it to $filename
$file_name=$file_name."'";//Concatenating here.
$extension = $file->getExtension($file->getOriginalExtension());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$file = $this->form->getValue('doc');
$filename = $file->getOriginalName();
$file_name=$fn.'_'.md5($fiename)."'";
$extension = $file->getExtension($file->getOriginalExtension());
```